# How can i convert all object Ids to string using query in MongoDB, note the structure is complex, So can't use $toString in $addFields and $project?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, nosql, objectid

I have a really deep-nested JSON object generated by aggregation query, but I want to convert all the object ids to string format. Tried $toString in $addFields and $project. Since the object is nested and contains an array of objects with object id. It's difficult to do using this. Is there any other way by which I can convert all object ids to string in MongoDB during querying?

Comment: Is unwind -> modify -> group an option?

Comment: Nope @Joe this was not necessary. Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the `$addFields` and `$project` operators to solve this. Although it took time. But the issue is resolved.

**Reference:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sample document and transform the `id` field in the `users` array.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("65680be1eedab2f7e7bfdc0a"),
  description: 'Test collection',
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Jack',
      id: ObjectId("65a4d269d08d8a3b5a5a557a")
    },
    {
      name: 'Joe',
      id: ObjectId("65a4d280d08d8a3b5a5a557b"),
    }
  ]
}
```

The query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
  $addFields: {
    users: {
      $map: {
        input: "$users",
        in: {
          $mergeObjects: [ 
            "$$this", 
            { id: { $toString: "$$this.id" } } 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ] )
```

The query transforms the `id` field in the `users` array from `ObjectId` type to `string` type, retaining rest of the document. E.g., from:

```
  ... users: [
    {
      name: 'Jack',
      id: ObjectId("65a4d269d08d8a3b5a5a557a")
    }, ...
```

to:

```
  ... users: [
    {
      name: 'Jack',
      id: "65a4d269d08d8a3b5a5a557a"
    }, ...
```

`$addFields` (or `$set`, an alias) can be used - specific fields in a document can be transformed while retaining remaining fields or adding new fields in the document. You can also use `$project` for similar functionality and mostly used for field projections.

---

Can this be tried without using the `$addFields` or `$project`? Yes, within a `db.collection.find` query you can (MongoDB v4.4 or higher), for example

```
db.collection.find( { },
{ 
    description: 1,
    users: {
      $map: {
        input: "$users",
        in: {
          $mergeObjects: [ 
            "$$this", 
            { id: { $toString: "$$this.id" } } 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
} )
```